# creating typescript type "one of interfaces"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create type which it's behaviour would be choosing between one of given interfaces.

Please note: in the example below `someTask` is data returned from the server! There is no actual initiation of it in the code!
For example:

```js
interface TaskA { foo: string }

interface TaskB { fee: string }

type Task = TaskB | TaskB 

const task:Task = someTask

console.log(task.fee)
```

The `console.log` function will yell at me:

> Property 'fee' does not exist on type 'Task'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `const task:Task` might be `TaskA` and `TaskA` has no `fee`.

Comment: And it actually isn't there probably. where is someTask initiated?

Comment: @HaimHouri The thing is I am building types for data that is returning from the server, therefor there is no `fee` at the moment I guess I am handling it wrong than. Any idea how can I make it work in this scenario?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi try doing `console.log(task.fee || task.foo). does this helps?

Comment: @HaimHouri even if it does, this example is obvious toy example. irl the interfaces will be huge and you can't really compare them like that every time. It's so weird there is no good way to deal with it

Comment: @obiwankenoobi Typescript isn't made for handling the logical way of the code, just for describing the types. What is the expected behaviour for you in case property fee is really missing from task?

Comment: @HaimHouri in my real life scenario I am getting back from the server object which its structure can be 1 of 3. All I need is validation it indeed one of those 3 later in my code

Answer (score 1):

The terms "union" and "intersection" as used in Typescript are mathematically correct, but still a bit confusing when applied to objects/interfaces. A union of two interfaces A and B is a type for all objects which are A or B. To work with such type reliably, the compiler has to be sure that only keys that are present in both A and B are used. In other words, a union of objects contains only an intersection of their keys. Conversely, an intersection of A and B, `A & B`, contains all keys from both A and B, that is, an intersection of interfaces is a union of their keys:

```
type A = { a: 1, b: 2, x: 3 }
type B = { a: 1, b: 2, y: 3 }

type U = keyof (A | B)  // a|b
type I = keyof (A & B)  // a|b|x|y
```

Since your objects don't have any common keys, their union is essentially an empty object (`{never: any}`). It cannot have any properties.

What you can do, is to introduce a *tagged* union, in which all member types have a common property ("tag") which enables the compiler to differentiate between them. Example:

```
type SomeTask<T, P extends {}> = { type: T } & P

type TaskOne = SomeTask<'first', {
    one: number
}>

type TaskTwo = SomeTask<'second', {
    two: number
}>

type Task = TaskOne | TaskTwo;

function validateTask(t: Task) {
    if (t.type === 'first')
        console.log(t.one);
    if (t.type === 'second')
        console.log(t.two);
}
```

Here, the compiler knows, that if the `type` is `first`, then the object is expected to have the `one` property.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

Make sure that you have defined property 'fee' in your object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be sure that the object you get from your server is a Task, you should add a User Defined Type Guard for either TaskA or TaskB. That way you can be sure that `someTask` has `fee` as a property, in this case.

```
interface TaskA { foo: string }

interface TaskB { fee: string }

type Task = TaskA | TaskB 

const task: Task = {fee: 'bar'};

console.log(isTaskA(task) ? task.foo : task.fee)

function isTaskA(value: TaskA | TaskB): value is TaskA {
    return value.hasOwnProperty('foo');
}
```